# tel: scheme not working on Android (MONACA hybrid App)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, monaca

```
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="x in con">
        <a href="tel:{{x.phoneNumber}}"><ons-icon icon="fa-phone" style="color:#37C837;"></ons-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{x.name}}</a>
      </ons-list-item>
```

Tapping on anchor link does not do anything. `{{x.phoneNumber}}`is a valid phone number.(checked in console)

Comment: What about using `ng-href` ?

Comment: Can you tell if there is cordova plugin for calling?

Comment: Are you using `whitelist plugin`? Have you set access origin in your `config.xml`?

Comment: `<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />`
 added the following`code`